# PHP Call to undefined function suddenly

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, include

I've been using a plugin on Wordpress that has been working for months. Suddenly I am seeing this error code:

**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function sb_get_single_sermon() in **/home/drcraigjohnson/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sermon-browser/sermon.php** on line **508**

I found where this is being called in sermon.php:

```
/**

* Create the shortcode handler

*

* Standard shortcode handler that inserts the sermonbrowser output into the post/page

*

* @param array $atts

* @param string $content

* @return string

*/

function sb_shortcode($atts, $content=null) {

    global $wpdb, $record_count, $sermon_domain;

    ob_start();

    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(

        'filter' => sb_get_option('filter_type'),

        'filterhide' => sb_get_option('filter_hide'),

        'id' => isset($_REQUEST['sermon_id']) ? $_REQUEST['sermon_id'] : '',

        'preacher' => isset($_REQUEST['preacher']) ? $_REQUEST['preacher'] : '',

        'series' => isset($_REQUEST['series']) ? $_REQUEST['series'] : '',

        'book' => isset($_REQUEST['book']) ? stripslashes($_REQUEST['book']) : '',

        'service' => isset($_REQUEST['service']) ? $_REQUEST['service'] : '',

        'date' => isset($_REQUEST['date']) ? $_REQUEST['date'] : '',

        'enddate' => isset($_REQUEST['enddate']) ? $_REQUEST['enddate'] : '',

        'tag' => isset($_REQUEST['stag']) ? stripslashes($_REQUEST['stag']) : '',

        'title' => isset($_REQUEST['title']) ? stripslashes($_REQUEST['title']) : '',

        'limit' => '0',

        'dir' => isset($_REQUEST['dir']) ? stripslashes($_REQUEST['dir']) : '', ),

    $atts);

    if ($atts['id'] != '') {

        if (strtolower($atts['id']) == 'latest') {

            $atts['id'] = '';

            $wpdb->query('SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1');

            $query = $wpdb->get_results(sb_create_multi_sermon_query($atts, array(), 1, 1));

            $atts['id'] = $query[0]->id;

        }

        $sermon = sb_get_single_sermon((int) $atts['id']);

        if ($sermon)

            eval('?>'.sb_get_option('single_output'));

        else {

            echo "<div class=\"sermon-browser-results\"><span class=\"error\">";

            _e ('No sermons found.', $sermon_domain);

            echo "</span></div>";

        }

    } else {

        if (isset($_REQUEST['sortby']))

            $sort_criteria = esc_sql($_REQUEST['sortby']);

        else

            $sort_criteria = 'm.datetime';

        if (!empty($atts['dir']))

            $dir = esc_sql($atts['dir']);

        elseif ($sort_criteria == 'm.datetime')

            $dir = 'desc';

        else

            $dir = 'asc';

        $sort_order = array('by' => $sort_criteria, 'dir' =>  $dir);

        if (isset($_REQUEST['pagenum']))

            $page = $_REQUEST['pagenum'];

        else

            $page = 1;

        $hide_empty = sb_get_option('hide_no_attachments');

        $sermons = sb_get_sermons($atts, $sort_order, $page, (int)$atts['limit'], $hide_empty);

        $output = '?>'.sb_get_option('search_output');

        eval($output);

    }

    $content = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    return $content;

}
```

It's being called from a file called frontend.php. Here is that code:

```
//Gets single sermon from the database
function sb_get_single_sermon($id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $id = (int) $id;
    $sermon = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT m.id, m.title, m.datetime, m.start, m.end, m.description, p.id as pid, p.name as preacher, p.image as image, p.description as preacher_description, s.id as sid, s.name as service FROM {$wpdb->prefix}sb_sermons as m, {$wpdb->prefix}sb_preachers as p, {$wpdb->prefix}sb_services as s where m.preacher_id = p.id and m.service_id = s.id and m.id = {$id}");
    $series = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ss.id as ssid, ss.name as series FROM {$wpdb->prefix}sb_sermons as m, {$wpdb->prefix}sb_series as ss WHERE m.series_id = ss.id and m.id = {$id}");
    if ($sermon) {
        if ($series) {
            $sermon->series = $series->series;
            $sermon->ssid = $series->ssid;
        }
        else {
            $sermon->series = '';
            $sermon->ssid = 0;
        }
        $file = $code = $tags = array();
        $stuff = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT f.id, f.type, f.name FROM {$wpdb->prefix}sb_stuff as f WHERE sermon_id = $id ORDER BY id desc");
        $rawtags = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT t.name FROM {$wpdb->prefix}sb_sermons_tags as st LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}sb_tags as t ON st.tag_id = t.id WHERE st.sermon_id = {$sermon->id} ORDER BY t.name asc");
        foreach ($rawtags as $tag) {
            $tags[] = $tag->name;
        }
        foreach ($stuff as $cur)
            ${$cur->type}[] = $cur->name;
        $sermon->start = unserialize($sermon->start);
        $sermon->end = unserialize($sermon->end);
        return array(
            'Sermon' => $sermon,
            'Files' => $file,
            'Code' => $code,
            'Tags' => $tags,
        );
    } else
        return false;
}
```

I have tried copying / pasting the function directly into admin.php but that breaks because it's declaring the function twice. So that tells me it's being called, but not recognized.. I think. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What changes occurred?

Comment: Put the function in a file which you include with `require_once` or `include_once`...so it only gets included once.

Comment: I wish I could say what has changed. The site doesn't have much activity. I've been going through various logs but can't seem to find anything. The development site still works fine. I'll try the fix above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar enough with PHP and WordPress plugin (I used to be long time ago) so I can't really explain why the sermons plugin was written that way. But I am having the same problem, and that broke the wp-admin site when I logged in as admin and tried to access appearance->widget from the left sidebar.

I enabled debug and traced the issue all the way to the sermon.php under home/{your_username}/{your_site}/wp-content/plugins/sermon-browser.

Just like what other said: `sb_get_single_sermon()` belongs to frontend.php, which is in the sb-includes folder, the same level as the sermon.php.

I think this is what it caused the error:
If you look at line #214 to #231 in sermon.php
[image]

It seems like the frontend.php only get loaded when you are NOT the admin!

I don't understand the reason behind, but after I moved that `require (SB_INCLUDES_DIR.'/frontend.php');` out before the `if (!is_admin())`, it works again.
[image]

And yea I used `require_once()` instead of `required()`, like what others suggested.